# Ребят, есть окно родительское с кнопкой, исчезает кнопка

Tags: python

Есть окно на нем кнопка, при нажатие исчезает image, и функционал
но только при параметре "global", без него окно не закрывается по нажатию

```
def oboi1():
    global oboi
    oboi = Toplevel(tk)
    oboi.geometry("500x200")                                     
    oboi.title("Выбор обоев")                                    
    oboi.resizable(width=False, height=False)                    
    screen12 = Label(oboi, image=sprosobi)                           
    screen12.grid(row=0, column=0)                                   
    bl = Button(oboi,image = animoct, command = animeoct)                                   
    bl.place(x=255,y=100, width=150, height=75)                    
    bl = Button(oboi, image = animoobrat)                                  
    bl.place(x=70,y=100, width=150, height=75)                    

def animeoct():
    oboiaime = Toplevel(tk)
    oboiaime.geometry("1280x900")                                     
    oboiaime.title("Обои")                                    
    oboiaime.resizable(width=False, height=False)                    
    oboi.withdraw()
```

Можно как то это исправить ?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должно работать без `global`:

```
bl = Button(oboi,image = animoct, command = lambda obj=oboi: animeoct(oboi))

def animeoct(obj):
    .....
    obj.withdraw()
```